# What should be the outcome if values from both groups are same in Mann-Whitney U test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I am trying to find results by applying Mann-Whitney U test in python, it was working fine so far. But I've come across this situation where values from both samples are same, for instance [only mentioning few values for example' sake]

Before = 1,1,1,1,1

After = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1

As per my understanding, if there's no significant difference (which isn't in this case), Null hypothesis should be accepted. But in python, I am getting the following error.
[image]
Does it work like this generally or just in python? Is it mandatory to have at least one unique value? Because clearly I am missing something. Any guidance please.

Comment: You seem to be dealing with a non-parametric version of $\frac00$.  The test is really whether the rankings of $Y$ appear to be independent of or dependent on the rankings of $X$ and your data provides nothing to help investigate this distinction:  it would be as bad if you tried linear regression where all the $x$ values were equal and all the $y$ values were equal.

Comment: @Henry, I understand now. Thank you :)